# string comparison in twig

Tags: symfony, twig

Someone can explain this?

In twig, I need to detect if certain controller is loaded. Depending on it, it should display a HTML block or another.

I have this comparison in twig template:

```
{% if app.request.attributes.get("_controller") == 'App\Controller\DefaultController::index' %}
```

Even when controller and action is actually "App\Controller\DefaultController::index" expression evaluates to false showing the block intended to be shown when the controller is other.

Besides explanation, I need to solution please.

by the way, when I print the controller name, using

```
{{ app.request.attributes.get("_controller") }}
```

I can check this strange behaviour.

Regards
Jaime

Comment: "In twig, I need to detect if certain controller is loaded" Are you sure you want that? It feels a bit off to have a template know the name of the controller.

Comment: Why you don't use the route name instead of the controller name ? Like this ```app.request.get('_route')```.

Comment: @Stratadox why? it is perfectly legal to need to know what is the URL of the current page. Depending on this, an image or other content should be shown.

Comment: @FabienSalles that brings me only the action, index, in this case.

Comment: @jstuardo By having the template detect the name of the controller, you're coupling the template to the *implementation* of that particular controller, rather than the concept of *a* controller. For reasons of maintainability it's a better practice to have the controller provide the view with everything it needs and potentially listen in on changes. In this case, I'd suggest sending a simple boolean parameter instead.

Comment: @Stratadox you are right.... finally I have implemented it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twig is reading the backslashes in your string as escape characters. To make it work you must escape the backslashes. Like this:

`'App\\Controller\\DefaultController::index'`

Comment: Thanks.. that did it. I didn't know twig also use backslash as escape character.